# How to change style for URI encoded SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, leaflet

In LeafletJS i want to use SVG icon with dynamic text in it.

```js
let svgicon = `<svg id='marker` + markers[i][4] + `' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64'>
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: #006aff;
            }      
            .cls-2 {
              font-size: 28px;
              fill: #fff;
              font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Montserrat;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M56.9679,24.9679A24.9679,24.9679,0,1,0,12.38928,40.42236h-.00067l18.4848,22.96552a1.38676,1.38676,0,0,0,2.22162.10583l17.86951-22.285H50.963A24.86853,24.86853,0,0,0,56.9679,24.9679Z"/>
        <text id='label` + markers[i][4] + `' class='cls-2' transform='translate(32 34)' text-anchor='middle'>` + markers[i][1] + `</text>
</svg>`

let url = encodeURI('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,' + svgicon).replace('#','%23');
```

So i end up with nice marker where custom text is part of SVG.

[image: LeafletJS inline SVG markers]

That custom data later could be pretty complicated. So i use simple example there. In browser we end up with something like this:

[image: LeafletJS URI encoded SVG marker in browser console]

Now the question is... how to apply external styles for `hover`, `mousedown`, `mouseover`, `click` or any other events?
Do i need to use client side (JS): decoding -> change style -> encoding?
On different events i want to style, outline, fill, to display/hide hidden paths and so on to make that marker more expressive/interactive/valuable. Sure i can apply CSS `filter` to change its color but it is too basic. I need to interact with each path or internal SVG style class independently.

Comment: wouldn't better if you give style, before load svg in the img tag?. Less code. Less misery.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any particular reason you're adding svg with `img` tag? Here's how I'd do it with SVG:

```js
const markers = [
  ['', '69', '', '', '1'],
  ['', '12', '', '', '2'],
  ['', '195', '', '', '3'],
];

const targetForMarkers = document.getElementById('target');
// batch to get more performance out of this
let batch = document.createElement('div');

markers.forEach(marker => {
  let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = getIcon(marker);

  // add event listeners like this
  wrapper.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('clicked:', e.target.id);
  });

  batch.append(wrapper);
});

targetForMarkers.append(batch);



// template
function getIcon(marker) {
  return `<svg id='marker` + marker[4] + `' class='marker' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64'>
        <path class="background" d="M56.9679,24.9679A24.9679,24.9679,0,1,0,12.38928,40.42236h-.00067l18.4848,22.96552a1.38676,1.38676,0,0,0,2.22162.10583l17.86951-22.285H50.963A24.86853,24.86853,0,0,0,56.9679,24.9679Z"/>
        <text id='label` + marker[4] + `' class='text' transform='translate(32 34)' text-anchor='middle'>` + marker[1] + `</text>
</svg>`;
}
```

```css
.marker {
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marker:hover .background {
  fill: #ec6161;
}

.background {
  fill: #006aff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.text {
  font-size: 28px;
  fill: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Montserrat;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: There is no any reason. This was the only way i figured out how to use SVG in LeafletJS. Checking your example.

Comment: I think you need another package to use HTML/SVG markers, e.g [first I found](https://github.com/iatkin/leaflet-svgicon). But Im not sure, haven't used LeafletJS yet.

Comment: Tnx a lot. Learning those examples now. Will update later.

Comment: This example is good, but could you please tell, how to apply GPS for every marker? Before it was similar to this `new L.marker([marker[2], marker[3]]).addTo(map);` . Currently it places default styled markers.

Comment: Im sorry, my knowledge of LeafletJS is bad. But you have to convert coordinates to CSS position (which LeafletJS has to do too). It appears that LeafletJS has some utility functions for that. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573160/get-absolute-pixel-coordinates-from-latlng) and look for similar ones.